# Eclipse keeps saying theres an error

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Ive tried deleting the project and importing it again, cleaning it up but it still says there's an error.

Its an android project and the little red "X" is on the highest directory and non of the sub directories.

Comment: So what error message do you see when you hover your mouse over the X? Or in the "problems" view?

Comment: Its not in any of the java or xml files just the directory.

Comment: Checked the project dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry found the problem, apparently eclipse doesn't like it when there is a "_" in a directory name, at least since the new updates that included the new gingerbread stuff.

Comment: you have to wait 24hrs before I can mark my own answer the answer